# Exponential - Trigonometric - Hyperbolic

Tags: trigonometry

The ratio of the belt tensions at the limiting value of friction is dependent on the coefficient of dry fiction $\mu$ and the angle of lap $\theta$.

For a V belt or pulley grove angle whose semi angle is "a" and is represented by the equation below:

$$\frac{T1}{T2} = e \mu \frac{\theta}{\sin a}$$

Determine the total angle of the V belt pulley grove.

I have so far

$$\frac{300~\text{N}}{58.7~\text{N}} = 0.2 \frac{160^{\circ}}{\sin a}$$

I am looking for help to complete this. So i can learn how to complete these.

I just don't know where to start

Comment: So do you need to solve the equation for $a$ or ... ?

Comment: Are you sure that equation is correct? Since $\sin a$ is dimensionless, the angle $\theta$ needs to be in radians if you want to get this right.

Comment: For a V belt or pulley groove angle whose semi angle is "a" and is represented by the equation. Determine the total angle of the V belt of pulley groove. This is what i need to do. But im a bit confused

Comment: So i need to swap 160 Degrees for 2.79253 Radians

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\sin a=\frac{58.7}{300}\times0.2\times\left(\left(168\times\frac{\pi}{180}\right)\,\text{rad}\right)\approx0.114745\implies a=0.114998\,\text{rad}=6.59^\circ.$$Edit: $168$ has since been changed to $160$, reducing the answer to $6.27^\circ$.

Comment: Yes i have just worked that out and was about to edit. One question i do have is you have $$0.114745$$. Then $$a = 0.114998 Rad = 6.59$$. Has the answer been rounded up to get a more precise angle. As i get $$6.261 Degree$$ with my answer as $$0.10928088$$. Also is their a blank equation for this? So i could try and input some more numbers to learn? Thanks.

Comment: @KyleAnderson The number changed when I went from $\sin a$ to $a$, but in radians $\sin a\approx a$. In general $a=\arcsin\frac{e\mu\theta T_2}{T_1}$.

Comment: Thank you, i will try this a few more times. So when you changed from $$sin a$$ to $$a$$ in radians $$sin a$$ is approximately $$a$$. Thats the only part im a bit confused on.

Comment: @KyleAnderson https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small-angle_approximation